# Smooth Angle Turning in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I was looking for ways to do smooth angle motion in Unity and I stumbled upon this clip of code:

```
IEnumerator SlideToPosition(Vector3 targetPos, float time)
{
    // Use an animation curve to make it look sweet!
    AnimationCurve smoothly = AnimationCurve.EaseInOut(0, 0, 1, 1);
    Transform myTrans = transform; // cache the transform for extra efficiency!
    float curTime = 0;
    Vector3 startPosition = myTrans.position;
    moving = true;
    while (curTime < time)
    {
        myTrans.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, targetPos, smoothly.Evaluate(curTime / time));
        curTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    moving = false;
    myTrans.position = targetPos;
}
```

This worked absolutely fantastically and I was looking for a way to do angled motion the same way as the poster of the original method (from 6 years ago) said it would be easy to do angular movement in the same way. I've tried everything and for the life of me can't seem to get it to rotate more than a degree or so. Can anyone help me out? Here is where I'm currently at:

```
IEnumerator rotateToPosition(Vector3 targetAngle, float time)
    {
        // Use an animation curve to make it look sweet!
        AnimationCurve smoothly = AnimationCurve.EaseInOut(0, 0, 1, 1);
        Transform myTrans = transform; // cache the transform for extra efficiency!
        float curTime = 0;
        Quaternion startAngle = myTrans.rotation;
        moving = true;
        while (curTime < time)
        {
            myTrans.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startAngle, Quaternion.Euler(targetAngle), smoothly.Evaluate(curTime / time));
            curTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
        moving = false;
        myTrans.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetAngle);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Not sure what `smoothly.Evaluate` is but I don't think you need it, just do `curTime` for the last parameter.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: How do I mark your comment as the answer? >_<

Comment: I'll post as an answer you can accept. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last parameter of Lerp is the time component - this is a float value between 0 and 1 which you can think of as the percentage of movement between the start and finish. i.e. a value of 0.5f would be exactly half way between (in your example) `startAngle` and `targetAngle`.

So, just do `curTime`for the last parameter, as you add to it each frame with `curTime += Time.deltaTime` this gradually moves between 0 and 1. If you want to vary the speed of the lerp then multiply this value e.g. to make it 50% faster use `curTime += Time.deltaTime * 1.5f`.