# How to lerp smoothly (Unity 3D)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So I'm creating this little fps game and my whole goal is just to make it satisfying and somewhat realistic. Flowy animations and such. However, I have a weapon sway script on my gun which does what it's supposed to, but when i added a walking animation and idle animation onto my gun as well, the weapon sway doesn't work (which makes sense i guess). So, I opted to try and use physics instead of animation to make my gun move up and down when I walk. I got it to "work," but it's not smooth at all. If you have any fixes, that would be greatly appreciated, and if you have an alternative way to do this then that would be amazing as well (i don't really like this way of doing this.) Thanks.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] Transform orientation;
    [SerializeField] Animator walkAnim;
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody gunRB;
    [SerializeField] Transform gun;
    Rigidbody rb;

    [Header("Other")]
    [SerializeField] float speed = 2000f;
    [SerializeField] float gunWalkResetSpeed = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] float walkSmoothness;
    [SerializeField] float walkSwayEffect;

    private Vector3 initialPos;

    bool canGoUp = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        initialPos = gun.localPosition;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-orientation.transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-orientation.transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && canGoUp || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && canGoUp || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && canGoUp || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && canGoUp)
        {
            canGoUp = false;
            Vector3 targetPos = new Vector3(0f, walkSwayEffect, 0f) + initialPos;
            gun.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(gun.localPosition, targetPos, walkSmoothness * Time.deltaTime);
            Invoke("GunDown", 0.2f);
        }
    }

    void GunDown()
    {
        Vector3 targetPos = new Vector3(0f, -walkSwayEffect, 0f) + initialPos;
        gun.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(gun.localPosition, targetPos, walkSmoothness * Time.deltaTime);
        Invoke("ResetWalk", 0.2f);
    }

    void ResetWalk()
    {
        canGoUp = true;
    }
}
```

I wanted to just get a smooth up and down lerp of the gun. Instead it just jerks up and down.

Comment: `Lerp` requires an increasing value as the last parameter. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70756411/smooth-angle-turning-in-unity/70849206#70849206. In this case though because this may not happen every frame like `Lerp` expects, you might want to look at a method that stores the last value like https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html

Comment: Log the values of `targetPos` and `walkSmoothness * Time.deltaTime`, tell us what you see.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can do this quite easily using Lerp, heres an example I made quickly, let me know if theres any issues and I can try to help:

```
public float gunStiffness = 5f;
public Transform gun;
public Vector3 gunOffset = new Vector3(5, -3, 2);

void Update() {
    Vector3 newPosition = GetNewGunPosition();
    gun.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(gun.localPosition, newPosition, gunStiffness * Time.deltaTime)
}

private Vector3 GetNewGunPosition() {
    Vector3 pos;
    pos.x = transform.localPosition.x + gunOffset.x;
    pos.y = transform.localPosition.y + gunOffset.y;
    pos.z = transform.localPosition.z + gunOffset.z;
    return pos;
}
```

Couple things to note:

- The gun must be a child of the player.
- I'm a 2D game dev so I'm not fully sure this will work, although I use a similar method to move my camera towards the player, so I don't see why it wouldn't.

Edit: this post is slightly vague, and is a bit of a "do this for me" question which the community won't really like, I reccomend you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and try to modify your question before you get flagged. (I learnt the hard way)